# How to set the max upload size value within php (not php.ini)?

Tags: php

I was trying to limit the size to 50bytes just to test it, but this approach isn't working for some reason.  I don't have access to the php.ini and would like to do this with code if possible.

The form:

```
 <form action='uploadFile.php' target='uploadIframe' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<div class='fieldRow'>
 <label>Select the file: </label>
 <input type='file' name='file' id='file' onChange='submitForm1(this)' />

 </div>
    </form>
<iframe style='border:0;' id='uploadIframe' name='uploadIframe'></iframe>
  <div id='successMessage'></div>
```

uploadFile.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
 $upload_dir = "../sitedata/auditfiles";
 $result["status"] = "200";
 $result["message"]= "Error!";

 if(isset($_FILES['file'])){

    echo "Uploading file... <br />";

     if ($_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
          $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
          $upload_dir.'/'.$filename);
           $result["status"] = "100";
          $result["message"]="File was uploaded successfully!";
```

Here is the issue:

```
      }elseif ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 50) {
      $result["status"] = "200";
      $result["message"]= "Error: Document size exceeds maximum limit of 5 MB.  Please reduce the file size and retry upload";
        }

     //initial code that worked but only does it through php.ini
      /*    elseif ($_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE) {
           $result["status"] = "200";
              $result["message"]= "The file is too big!";/**/
     } else {
             $result["status"] = "500";
           $result["message"]= "Unknown error!";
       }
      }
     ?>
    </body>
    </html>



     <script>
      $(function () {
            $('#successMessage', window.parent.document).html('<?php echo htmlspecialchars($result["message"]); ?>');
     });
    </script>

 function submitForm1(upload_input_field){
  //alert("works");
   upload_input_field.form.submit();
   upload_input_field.disabled = true;
   return true;

 }
```

Comment: Quick answer: .htaccess / .user.ini … Inside of script does not work.

Comment: Try `if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 50)` then use an `else/elseif` which what you're doing now, is allowing larger files first, rather than checking if it first exceeds 50.

Comment: You can use ini_set instead of actually editing the php.ini file.

Comment: I have seen it done before...  so this isn't a duplicate based upon that other post.  I am using php 5.3.

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1,048,576" />  This is not a duplicate, and I found an answer.  This has to be within the form and above the <input type="file">

Comment: $upload_errors = array( UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE  => "Larger than form MAX_FILE_SIZE.",
 
);
$error = $_FILES['file_upload']['error'];
$message = $upload_errors[$error];

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score 3):

`upload_max_filesize` is in `PHP_INI_PERDIR` mode and from the PHP documentation:

> **PHP_INI_PERDIR** Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini (since PHP 5.3)

So, your choices are php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini, you can't set it in the script using `ini_set`.